# I want to export data from a BLE112 dongle on BLE GUI to a csv or other similar type file

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, export-to-csv, bluegiga

I have a device connected to my Bluegiga BLE112 dongle that sends temperature measurements every second. I am using BLE GUI to connect to and receive the data. I would like to store all the measurements in a csv file so I can import it into another program and analyze it. I have already enabled indications, so the data shows up and updates in the 'raw' column as shown:

[image: BLE GUI reading]

but I cannot figure out how to store or export that data.

Answer (score 0):

Unless BLE GUI has changed significantly (I haven't used it in about 1-2 years), you can't do anything like this.

You'd need to write your own app or laptop/desktop communication and parser/save.

HOWEVER! One option you could use that I used to do is try out my BLE Log parser: 
http://www.sureshjoshi.com/development/summer-of-bluegiga-code/
http://www.sureshjoshi.com/development/blegui-log-parsing-and-filtering/

I wrote a little tool a couple years ago which would parse data coming from the log, and place it all in one place, so I could copy and use that elsewhere (I was using it for tracking advertising data on multiple devices).

NOTE: I haven't touched that code since that blog was written - no idea if it'll work.